# Stripe Subscription update the plan immediately without charging them

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

I've created one month subscription in stripe, after somedays I switched to quarterly plan, but I want that the new plan charge will get applied after the first plan is completed then after start new quarterly plan and invoice & charges should be applied after my current plan expires, how it possible?

Comment: Need to show the code you used so someone can even start guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can take an existing Stripe Subscription and convert it to a Subscription Schedule (see https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription). Once you've done that, you can use Subscription Schedules `phases` to control when future changes to a Subscription should happen.

Stripe has a sample use case here(https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#changing-subscriptions), but the general idea would be:

- Convert your Subscription to a Subscription Schedule
- Update the Subscription Schedule to add an additional phase that ends after the current phase and uses the new, quarterly plan.